# php passing strings to external diff command

Tags: php, shell, diff

My program generates two strings and I want them compared by the external diff tool. The diff tool accepts only files/directories as arguments. That's `diff file1 file2` works perfectly but `diff "hello" "world"` doesn't work. Is there a way to pass my strings directly to `diff` without creating any temporary files? Thanks.

Comment: What is "the external diff tool"?

Comment: what prograsm you are using for diff ? (more details please)

Comment: The linux diff tool. Simply $> diff

Comment: And what's wrong with PHP string functions to get the diff?

Comment: In my case, the strings are probably multi-line. I found diff's -y options quite handy to help me get output that's easy to parse without too much code. That's why I pick diff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the shell, you can use temporary pipes.

```
diff <(echo "string 1") <(echo "string 2")
```

Use the backticks operator or any other method to execute the command in php. For details on executing commands, see the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php

Make sure, you properly escape the strings.

**EDIT:** This feature is called temporary pipes. So the shell translates it to a file descriptor.

```
iblue@nerdpol:~$ echo <(echo "string")
/dev/fd/63
iblue@nerdpol:~$ cat <(echo "string")
string
```

For a detailed explanation see http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156?page=0,1

Comment: Works! Could you elaborate how <(echo "string 1") can simulate a file in shell?

Comment: AFAIK It simply attaches two pipes to the diff command, like two STDIN's. But I don't know why and how it exactly works. That's why I asked the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195117/two-pipes-to-one-command